# can't get akka streams / alpakka S3 to work in simple case

Tags: akka, alpakka

I'm doing what I think is a very simple thing to check that alpakka is working:

```
val awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create("xxx", "xxx")
val credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds)
implicit val staticCreds = S3Attributes.settings(S3Ext(context.system).settings.withCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
  .withS3RegionProvider(new AwsRegionProvider {val getRegion: Region = Region.US_EAST_2}))

val d = S3.checkIfBucketExists(action.bucket)
d foreach { msg => log.info("mgs: " + msg.toString)}
```

When I run this I get

```
 msgs: NotExists
```

But the bucket referred to by action.bucket does exist, and I can access it using these credentials.  What's more, when I modify the credentials (by changing the secret key), I get the same message.  What I should get, according to the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html), is AccessDenied.

I got to this point because I didn't think the environment was picking up on the right credentials - hence all the hard-coded values.  But now I don't really know what could be causing this behavior.

Thanks

Update: The action object is just a case class consisting of a bucket and a path.  I've checked in debug that action.bucket and action.path point to the things they should be - in this case an S3 bucket.  I've also tried the above code with just the string bucket name in place of action.bucket.

Comment: can you provide some details on `action`

Comment: if you print out the `staticCreds` is it all expected? including the region?

Comment: Not sure how to do that - toString on staticCreds gives an opaque identifier (akka.stream.alpakka.s3.S3SettingsValue@4193ff57).  Do you know how to print the values from that structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my carelessness . . .

An errant copy added an extra implicit system to the mix.  Some changes were made to implicit materializers in akka 2.6 and I think those, along with the extra implicit actor system, made for a weird mix.